# Python - value replacement, calculation, and print - simplification

Tags: python, python-3.5

Trying to understand how I can simplify the following code snipet which is part of a 'while' loop, in the most basic way possible.

```
 a1,b1 = a,b
 a = b1
 b = a1 + b1
 print(a1, end="")
```

I don't want to simplify the entire 'while' loop, just the above snipet for replacement, calculation, and print. For additional insight, here's the entire while loop.

```
while element < end_element:
    element = element + 1
    a1,b1 = a,b
    a = b1
    b = a1 + b1
    print(a1, end="")
```

Any insight here is welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: fyi: `element = element + 1` can be changed to `element += 1`

Comment: Excellent! Great input here, didn't think about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.It will work.

```
 print(a, end="")
 a,b = b,a+b
```

And your entire will look like this :

```
while element < end_element:
    element += 1
    print(a, end="")
    a,b = b,a+b
```

Comment: I think you meant `element += 1` instead of `element += element`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked by moving the print statement above "a,b = b,a+b" which made sure to include the first number in the sequence. When leaving the print statement at the end as per the original code, the first number in the sequence was being bumped up by the addition prior to the print. My next question would be how can (instead of end=""), how can I get the output to be comma delimited, I've tried print (a, end=","), however, there's a trailing comma after the last digit which I'm trying to get rid of. I've also tried (a, sep",") however, that just prints the numbers vertically.

Comment: @dpx You would probably need an `if` statement to do that. Something like: `if element == end_element: print(a) else: print(a, end=",")`

Comment: @dpx Accept the answer by ticking it.So that this issue can be closed.Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
a,b = b,a+b
```

This appears to work in the examples I tested, and is intended for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that's the most short way to do that `while` loop:

```
while end_element:
    print(a, end="")
    end_element, a,b = end_element - 1, b,a+b
```

Comment: You are printing a modified 'a'. While in the original logic the one 'a' that he need is the old one before change.